# Need to get names from a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, nested

Hi I have a simple nested list.
My goal is to get items at index 0 of each inner list and assign it to a variable "names". So i want to have a variable with only names

```
numerical_list = [['Casey', 176544.328149], ['Riley', 154860.66517300002]]
```

Tried and failed

```
for i in numerical_list:
    list = i[0]

new_list = [list]

print(list)
```

Want:
new_list to print out Casey, Riley

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
print([v[0] for v in numerical_list])
```

Note that you should not use `list` as a variable name. That would hide the built-in meaning of that word.

That printout will look like a list, because it is one. You can use a loop over that resultant list's values to get whatever format you want. For example,

```
for i in [v[0] for v in numerical_list]:
    print(i, end= ' ')
```

prints, in Python 3,

```
Casey Riley
```

Or, if you understand the `join` method,

```
print(' '.join([v[0] for v in numerical_list]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using *list comprehension*, you may also achieve it using `map()` as:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> numerical_list = [['Casey', 176544.328149], ['Riley', 154860.66517300002]]

>>> list(map(itemgetter(0), numerical_list))
['Casey', 'Riley']
```

OR, a small hack by converting it to `dict` (just for illustration, not suggested) as:

```
>>> dict(numerical_list).keys()
['Casey', 'Riley']   # Note: As `dict` are not ordered, you may loose the actual order in list
                     #       Use `collections.OrderedDict` for maintaining order
```

Then for printing the content of the list as string, print it with `join()` as:

```
 print(' '.join(my_list))  # where `my_list` is holding the list of words
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a different variable name, not `list`, which is a built-in Python feature.

Something like this would work:

```
new_list = [sublist[0] for sublist in numerical_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_list = [sublist[0] for sublist in numerical_list]
print new_list`

Answer (score 0):

You can, also, use `groupby` from `itertools` module like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

numerical_list = [['Casey', 176544.328149], ['Riley', 154860.66517300002]]

new_list = [key for key, _ in groupby(numerical_list, lambda x : x[0])]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Casey', 'Riley']
```